# Could not find or load main class - using javafx mobile plugin on Android

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports

I was able to build/compile my project using `javafxmobileplugin`.The command I used was "gradlew androidInstall". I was able to install the apk in my device, but while launching a blank screen appears. On the terminal, I could see the error `"Could not find or load main class"`.Please help.

My build.gradle is as follow:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b7'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'ch.nest.application.Main'



    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

jfxmobile {
    android {
        applicationPackage = 'ch.nest.application'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
//            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/']
//            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
//            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
//            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
//            res.srcDirs = ['res']
//            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
}
project(':app') {
    preloaderClassName = "ch.nest.application.Main"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [Gluon-plugin](http://gluonhq.com/products/tools/ide-plugins/) for NetBeans?

You can create a new JavaFX project with it, and it will create for you all the folders (main, desktop, android, ios) and a `build.gradle` file.

You just need to update the jfxmobile plugin version to 1.0.0-b8 (you could use b9-SNAPSHOT for very last changes).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'ch.nest.application.Main'

jfxmobile {
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = [ 'ch.nest.application.**.*' ]
    }
}
```

You can build and test this on your desktop, or run any ot the tasks like `androidInstall` to test it on your mobile.

Once you have tested it, just provide the full code to the respective packages and try it again.

Comment: Well,I was able to do that.Also, how can we add external libraries to gluon project.

Comment: How to add gluon plugin to existing project in netbeans. Please help.

Comment: Could you please create another question for this?